# Deployment order in Jboss 7.2

Tags: deployment, jboss

is there a way to set up a deployment order in Jboss 7.2 ?

I know is not a comon thing but i'd like to deploy an .EAR and some .wars in certain order. I dont develope this components so i dont have any control over them. I tried with the jboss-all.xml but i found in redhat page that this is not an order rule:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html/configuration_guide/deploying_applications#deploying_apps_using_console

"IMPORTANT
Although the jboss-all.xml file and other deployment descriptors allow you to declare dependencies that the server does not otherwise detect, it is not a strict ordering feature. JBoss EAP assumes that all dependencies specified in the deployment descriptor have already been deployed or are available. If there are missing dependencies, JBoss EAP does not automatically deploy them, and the deployment fails."

Thanks a lot!